# Installing rails with ruby 1.9.2 after 1.8.7 was previously installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I previously had ruby 1.8.7 on rails installed. I then downloaded ruby 1.9.2 and tried to get this running on rails also.

I extracted the 1.9.2 folder and navigated to it via ruby command prompt and entered:

```
   ruby setup.rb
```

I then updated the gems to the latest version using the line:

```
gem update --system 1.8.15
```

Now when I try to run the next line from the tutorial I am following an error occurs. The line of code is:

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.11
```

I receive the following error when running from prompt at location (C:\Ruby192\bin) or from (.\Desktop\rubygems-1.8.15):

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    marshall datatoo short
```

Anyone got any ideas of why this is happening or how I can go about setting up my 1.9.2 an alternative way so that it is mounted on rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should look into using rvm.  http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

It allows you to install rubies per project.

EDIT:

It looks like you may be using Windows.  Give pik a try.  https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/

Comment: I have installed pik but am unsure now as to how to use it

Comment: There is a readme in the project:
https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/blob/master/README.rdoc

Or you can reference this blog post:
http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2010/08/installing-rails-30-ruby-192-and-pik-on.html